# Hadoop 2.1.0-beta wordcount example error

Tags: hadoop

I'm new at hadoop and a bit confused.. My version is 2.1.0-beta and I followed the guide for the cluster setup (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html).

I'm trying to run the wordcount example as in http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount.
The command 
`./hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/user/input/inputfile /opt/hdfsdata/`
gives me :

DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

13/09/22 20:41:06 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not 
13/09/22 20:41:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/09/22 20:41:06 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not 
13/09/22 20:41:06 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not 
copyFromLocal: `/opt/hdfsdata/': No such file or directory

/opt/hdfsdata does exist.

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

**/opt/hdfsdata** probably represents a path on your local FS, while the command **copyFromLocal** expects an HDFS path. Make sure have this path existing on your HDFS, or have permissions to create it inside HDFS.

If you want to use it with local FS, use the complete path with proper scheme :
**file:///opt/hdfsdata**. But why would you use an HDFS command for this. What's the problem with normal **cp**??

**In response to your comment :**

You have copied the file into your **local FS**, which is **file:///opt/hdfsdata/**, but your job is looking for this path inside HDFS. This is why you are getting this error. And this is why **dfs -ls** is not showing anything. Either copy the file inside HDFS or use the local path in your job.

**Try this :**

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /opt/hdfsdata/

bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/user/input/inputfile /opt/hdfsdata/

Now run your job.
```

Also, no need to use hdfs:/ while running HDFS shell command.

Comment: Yes /opt/hdfsdata is a path on the local FS and I've tried the following: sudo ./hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/user/input/inputfile hdfs://1.2.3.4:9000/input/inputfile. It gave : No such file or directory. How do I create it?

Comment: **No such file or directory** for what? src? or dest??

Comment: No actual need to use HDFS commands, I just tried to do what the guide showed for the wordcount example. No such file or directory for dest (hdfs://1.2.3.4:9000/input/inputfile). How do I upload the inputfile to an HDFS directory so as to use it for the wordcount?

Comment: Then definitely the dest doesn't exist. Please make sure you are using the correct path with correct name because this how the command works. Also, make sure you have create permission.

Comment: OK, I uploaded the file on /opt/hdfsdata on my namenode. As for the wordcount example, the datanodes of my cluster will have access to the input file through HDFS so as to execute the required map/reduce tasks, right?

Comment: Running the wordcount example gave me this error `ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:user (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://1.2.3.4:9000/opt/hdfsdata/inputfile`. Inputfile does exist in /opt/hdfsdata but it's not accessible by that address. I ran `dfs -ls hdfs:/` but it didn't return the file name. The command I used for copying the file was `sudo ./hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/user/input/inputfile file:///opt/hdfsdata/`.

Answer (score 0):

go through the below link it will gives you solution of your wordcount program.

http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_1_--_Running_WordCount#Basic_Hadoop_Admin_Commands

OR

run the below command,,

```
hadoop dfs -ls /opt/hdfsdata 
/**if this command return your /opt/hdfsdata is directory then you can 
 easily write your file into hdfsdata directory. */
```

if this command return no such file or directory run below command.

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir /opt/hdfsdata
```

Comment: I ran the two commands above but they both gave  `/opt/hdfsdata: No such file or directory`. The directory exists but hadoop can't see it for some reason.

Comment: Why every mkdir command (hadoop dfs -mkdir /opt/hdfsdata) returns 'No such file or directory'? Isn't it obvious that it doesn't exist and I want to create it? Btw, the link for the wordcount example seems to be deprecated for my version of hadoop.   Running `./hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/opt/hdfsdata` gives `Call From master/1.2.3.4 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;`

Comment: It gave `DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
13/09/24 10:47:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

Comment: run " hadoop fs -ls / " if this command not working run `hadoop datanode -start` OR `hadoop datanode -rollback` this command show you have permission or not for creting directory in HDFS if not then it will through permission exception.

Comment: `hadoop datanode -start` gave `STARTUP_MSG: java = 1.7.0_40
************************************************************/
INFO datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [T                                             ERM, HUP, INT]
Usage: java DataNode [-rollback | -regular]

13/09/24 11:46:48 WARN datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
13/09/24 11:46:48 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
13/09/24 11:46:48 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at master/1.2.3.4`. What does it do?

Comment: this command throw permission exception for your hdfs and start the port of datanode for read write operation in your case it suggest use 'hadoop dfs -rollback' run this command . btw what `hadoop dfs -ls /` command return

Comment: 'hadoop dfs -ls /' gave the message "DEPRECATED..." I posted above. Rollback command gives a lot of info messages. Then it hangs, last lines of output are `13/09/24 12:24:20 INFO datanode.DataBlockScanner: Added bpid=BP-1595002398-127.0.1.1-1379953712208 to blockPoolScannerMap, new size=1`.  I also saw in 1.2.3.4:50070 that the master (1.2.3.4) is added to the live datanodes list. Is this right?

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong, so I'll try with the stable 1.2.1 version. Can anyone post a guide that makes hadoop work in debian squeeze 64bit? One that will actually make it work.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: your welcome..use this link for hadoop installation http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_1_--_Running_WordCount#Basic_Hadoop_Admin_Commands

Comment: Thanx for the link, I'm still getting errors in slaves' logs and jobtracker and tasktrackers won't launch: `FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority:  1.2.3.4:9001

         at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:149)
         at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:130)...` This happens when I run ./start-mapred.sh. ./start-dfs.h runs OK.

Comment: I managed to run the example with this command: '/opt/hadoop/bin/./hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.1.0-beta.jar wordcount file:///home/user/input/ /home/user/outdir' . I didn't upload the input file to hdfs. Results came out and the output files were loaded in a directory named outdir that can only be seen by running `hadoop dfs -ls /`.                                                           1. How can I view the results' files;                               2. Using a local file means no map/reduce tasks or data were split to my cluster's slaves?